# How to send a http response using koajs

Tags: node.js, koa, koa2

I'm trying to validate a webhook via facebook. So facebook hits my url `my-url/facebook/receive` within my route in nodejs i'd do `res.send(req.query['hub.challenge']);` to send an http response.

I'm using KoaJS. From what i understand, Koajs merges the request and response object into `ctx` but when reading through the docs I can't find anything along the lines of `ctx.send` or similar to send a http response.

Can anyone give me some direction or links.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To send the body of a response, you can simply do `ctx.response.body = 'Hello'`. There are many aliases attached to `ctx`, so you don't necessarily have to reference the `response` or `request` yourself. Doing `ctx.body = 'Hello'` would be the same as the code above.

If you wanted to set headers, you would use the `ctx.set()` method. For example: `ctx.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')`.

To access the `query` parameters, you would use `ctx.request.query['some-key']` (or simply the alias `ctx.query['some-key']`).

All of the different request/response methods are documented pretty well at the [Koa](http://koajs.com/) website along with a list of aliases attached to `ctx`. I highly recommend you give it a read.

Comment: I spent a few hours reading after I posted my questions and figured it out :) your answer is spot on, though. Thank you very much :) Hopefully, your answer will help someone else in the future :)

Comment: Where do you get `ctx.set` in documentation?

Comment: [Here](https://koajs.com/#response-set-field-value-) are the docs for `ctx.response.set`.  You can also see in the [response aliases](https://koajs.com/#response-aliases) section that `ctx.set` is aliased to the equivalent `response.set` method.